# js backgroundImage() fade in on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using javascript to display my background image because I'd like to have a random background image on each reload. Anyway, because of this my typical CSS transitions and animations won't do, because instead of fading the background it fades the text inside of my body.

Is there any way around this so that on each reload the background fades in?

This is the code I am using to display the random image:

```
var randomImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 18) + 1;
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/" + randomImage + ".jpg)";
```

and I'm unsure how to make it fade in... any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/
http://jsfiddle.net/wby2xf6f/1/

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  transition: opacity 5s;
  content: "";
  background: url(http://www.wina.ugent.be/style/img/h1.png);
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}

div.fadein:after {
    opacity:1;
}
```

And then add the class `.fadein` with Javascript/JQuery.
http://jsfiddle.net/wby2xf6f/1/

On a sidenote: it might be better to select the background-image at random on the server side (using php/ruby/whatever).

Updated, but less semantic version: http://jsfiddle.net/wby2xf6f/5/

```
.fill {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-1;
    display:none;
    background:url(http://www.wina.ugent.be/style/img/h1.png);
}

$('.fill').fadeIn(5000)
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question I don't think... Because I am loading the image in via javascript I can't style it like I want with CSS because it is added as a html style...

Comment: What about my second version? You can set the background with javascript that way.

Answer (score 0):

This example with your code above

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var img1 = "http://www.clarkcraft.co.uk/images/des/48040.jpg";
    var img2 = "http://glamorouslymommy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/small-background1.jpg";
   setInterval(function(){ 
       var randomImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 18) + 1;
       if(randomImage<=5){     
$("div").css("background","url("+img2+")").show().fadeOut("slow");              $("div").css("background","url("+img1+")").show().fadeIn("slow");
       }
       else{
$("div").css("background","url("+img1+")").show().fadeOut("slow");           $("div").css("background","url("+img2+")").show().fadeIn("slow");
       }
   }, 1000);
});
```

```css
div {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display:none"></div>
```